# Add an event listener to C# class property reflectively

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to create an `OleTableAttribute` that I will apply to a class `MyTable` alongside a `System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute` so that it would look something like this:

```
[Table(Name="MyTable")]
[OleTable]
public class MyTable
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int pk_id { get; set; }
    /*...*/
}
```

What I'd like the `OleTableAttribute` to do is look for any `[Column]` attributed properties in the class that it is marked on, and reflectively add some type of listener to the setter method if it has one.  The focus of this question is really how to do the reflective monitoring-setup of setter calls; just a simple "hey-its-been-called" signal is all I need.  Is this possible?

Comment: seems like [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) is something I need to check out here.

Answer (score 0):

[PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) works.  Using the `[NotifyPropertyChanged]` aspect will decorate all your properties behind the scenes with just the type of signalling I'm looking for here.  Then the `[OleTable]` can treat it's attributed class `as INotifyPropertyChanged` and add its own PropertyChanged event.